# Mini DVI port male to thunderbolt female

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, displayport, thunderbolt-display

I use the old 2007 white macbook (that works great). There's a thunderbolt display lying idle in our office, and I wish to connect it to my macbook. The macbook has a mini DVI port. I searched online for a mini DVI male to thunderbolt female adapter, but couldn't find anything. Does such a thing not exist?

Answer (score 0):

No. 
The Thunderbolt Display works only on Thunderbolt ports. Not even on mini-display-port (even if the connector is the same)